# get numeric value for values in array

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I need to add some sort of matching count in my generated string, but I have no idea how. Is there a way to add some count to array?

I have the following code (a database query is executed right before the while):

```
while (!$products->EOF) {
      $purchasedArray[] = array('products_model'=>$products->fields['products_model'],
                                'products_name'=>$products->fields['products_name'],
                                'final_price'=>$products->fields['final_price'],
                                'products_quantity'=>$products->fields['products_quantity']);
      $products->MoveNext();
}
foreach ($purchasedArray as $purchased) {
    $formattedProductname[] = $purchased['products_name'];
    $formattedPrice[] = $purchased['final_price'];
    $formattedUnits[] = $purchased['products_quantity'];
}
$listFinal = implode('|', $formattedProductname);
```

Now, this is all great and works fine, but I would need the following output:

```
product1=cookie|10.00|2&product2=paper|5.00|17&product3=...
```

I'm searching and searching, but just can't seem to find any info on how to add that count (product**1**, product**2**...)
My could should (probably) look something like this:

```
foreach ($purchasedArray as $purchased) {
    $formattedProducts[] = 'product'.**$position** . '=' . $purchased['products_name'] . '|' . $purchased['final_price'] . '|' . $purchased['products_quantity'];
    $formattedProductname[] = $purchased['products_name'];
    $formattedPrice[] = $purchased['final_price'];
    $formattedUnits[] = $purchased['products_quantity'];
}

$listFinal = implode('&', $formattedProducts);
$listFinalProducts = implode('|', $formattedProductname);
```

but I have absolutely no idea how to get that `$position` part... Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by the key of the array:

```
foreach ($purchasedArray as $key=>$purchased) {
    $formattedProducts[] = 'product'. $key . '=' . $purchased['products_name'] . '|' .  $purchased['final_price'] . '|' . $purchased['products_quantity'];
    $formattedProductname[] = $purchased['products_name'];
    $formattedPrice[] = $purchased['final_price'];
    $formattedUnits[] = $purchased['products_quantity'];
}
```

Or you could do it by adding a count:

```
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($purchasedArray as $purchased) {
        $count++;
        $formattedProducts[] = 'product'. $count . '=' . $purchased['products_name'] . '|' .  $purchased['final_price'] . '|' . $purchased['products_quantity'];
        $formattedProductname[] = $purchased['products_name'];
        $formattedPrice[] = $purchased['final_price'];
        $formattedUnits[] = $purchased['products_quantity'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$idx=1;
foreach ($purchasedArray as $purchased) {
    //$formattedProducts[] = 'product'.**$position** . '=' . $purchased['products_name'] . '|' . $purchased['final_price'] . '|' . $purchased['products_quantity'];
    $formattedProducts[] = 'product'.$idx. '=' . $purchased['products_name'] . '|' . $purchased['final_price'] . '|' . $purchased['products_quantity'];
    $idx++;
    $formattedProductname[] = $purchased['products_name'];
    $formattedPrice[] = $purchased['final_price'];
    $formattedUnits[] = $purchased['products_quantity'];
}
```